# Why can't i use "I haven't known" someone in English

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

A few days ago, I read this sentence in "English grammar in use" by Raymond Murphy:

> We don't know where we're going for our holiday yet.

I thought present perfect must be used here as: we haven't known...yet. But when I searched on the internet, everyone says that I can not use present perfect "I haven't known" here.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstand the meaning of *know*. It does not describe an action that you perform, but rather a *state* you are in. You cannot perform the action of *knowing* something at a specific moment.

You *can*, however, *find out* or *discover* something. From that moment on, you *know* that something.

You *could* rephrase your sentence with a present perfect:

> We *haven't decided* where we're going for our holiday yet.

The difference between *decide* and *know* is that *decide* describes an action, so you can talk about it as an action, whereas *know* is a static verb, which does not describe an action.

---

Ok, there is actually a case where *know* can describe an action, the so-called "biblical" sense, i.e. have sexual relations with someone. But a sentence like *I haven't known her yet* will seem very strange to modern speakers!

Comment: I haven't known the combination to that safe since 1985.

Comment: @Davo good one! If there is any confusion left from the OP I might add some more detail. For now, I have proposed for the question to be moved to ELL, where I think it is a better fit.

Comment: I haven't known him since 2015, only since 2016